# JSON get arrays from string php

Tags: php, json

I need some help with this script, it only return the state, and it needs to return the showtime and freeseats.

```
$json_string = 'http://framecreators.nl/efteling/data.php';
$var = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_string), true);
foreach($var['AttractionInfo'] as $info) { 
    if($info['Id'] == 'raveleijn') {
        $informatie = $info['ShowTimes'];
        echo $info['State'];
        break;
    } 
}
echo $informatie;
```

My JSON File = http://framecreators.nl/efteling/data.php

Comment: Please include all relevant code and example data inline in the question, and not as links.

Comment: The showtime is NULL.

Comment: Not for id Raveleijn :)

Comment: PLs, check {"Id":"raveleijn","Type":"Show","MapLocation":"7","WaitingTime":null,"OpeningHours":null,"State":"gesloten","StateColor":"clear","StatePercentage":null,"ShowTimes":null,"HorecaTimes":null}

Answer (score 0):

The `$info['ShowTimes']` is `null`. Try `var_dump($informatie)`
Try this:

```
$json_string = 'http://framecreators.nl/efteling/data.php';
$var = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_string), true);
foreach($var['AttractionInfo'] as $info) {

    if($info['Id'] == 'raveleijn') {
        $informatie = $info['ShowTimes'];
        echo $info['State'];

        break;
    }

}
var_dump($informatie);
```

EDITED for request:

```
$json_string = 'http://framecreators.nl/efteling/data.php';
$var = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_string), true);
foreach($var['AttractionInfo'] as $info) {

    if($info['Id'] == 'raveleijn') {
        $informatie = $info;


        break;
    }

}
echo is_null($informatie['State'])? 'Not set' : $informatie['State']; 
echo '<br>';
echo is_null($informatie['ShowTimes'])? 'Not set' : $informatie['ShowTimes'];
```

But I dont see "FreeSeats" index in your input data, please check your input data

Comment: Omg thanks. But how do i get the var ShowDateTime and FreeSeats?

Comment: @MickGeen ShowDateTime and FreeSeats aren't in the json. Paste it into jsonlint.com or install a json pretty-print extension in your browser to see the json data in a better way.

Comment: @JimL have right, you should check your input data.